# How to put the Camera input on the screen and blur it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, camera

I'm fairly new to iOS development.

What I want to achive is to put the stream from the camera in a UIView class. (and size it with a frame).
So i don't need controls or the possibility to capture images, just on the screen what the camera sees.

Furthermore, i want that view to be blurred. Is there a way (or a library) to put a gaussian blur on that videostream?

Thank you!

Comment: That's probably going to use a ton of CPU power - blur is not a cheap operation.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but it is actualy a school-assignment, just for showing what we can achive after a basic introducion into Obj C. Performance is not that important.

Comment: *Performance is not important* Ugh. Schools. Anyway, I mean it would be pretty close to unusable.

Comment: Assuming you use the CPU, that's true, but instead you could use the GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GPUImage https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage try realtime effects they provide. That will solve your problem for sure.

Comment: I'm trying this and i looks pretty cool, but when i try to ad a camera view, I only see the first frame and then the compiler craches only giving me (lldb) as an error...

I used the sample code, so i don't know where it goes wrong.

Here is what i wrote:

[link](http://pastebin.com/9LPpXyMa) 

@Brad Larson

Comment: @WouterVandersyppe - Your problem there, which you might have figured out by now, is that you don't hold on to your camera anywhere. As soon as that method is finished, your camera will be deallocated, tearing down the rest of your filter chain. You need to have your camera be assigned to an instance variable in order for it to hang around (under ARC, at least).

Comment: @BradLarson Hi I'm working with your GPUImage sdk and it's awesome. I'm having difficulty trying to integrate it with a particular QR scanning library named ZBar though, which creates its own AVCaptureSession and VideoDataOutput, and I can't seem to add its output to the session created in GPUImageVideoCamera or vice versa. Would you have any advice on the matter?

For reference, I'm trying to create a blurred effect around the target scan area of a qr scanner.

Comment: @Carlin - It's probably not best to ask this in a comment on an unrelated question. In any case, you might be better off ditching ZBar and looking at the new AV Foundation additions in iOS 7. That's all I can say without breaking NDA.

Answer (score 0):

To display the camera on screen without controls you will need to use AVFoundation. Take a look at Apple's [SquareCam sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html).

As for the blur a simpler solution might be creating semi-transparent image with a blur effect and placing it about the camera view.